# Change the axis type on Google line chart

Tags: google-visualization

Im getting some Google analytic data from the server and passing it to a Google chart as JSON. I cannot figure out how to get the chart to render as a date axis with lines. I now looks like this http://screencast.com/t/VdPNzW6JDlPQ and I need it to look like this http://screencast.com/t/yCzUdurhB.

This is the code

```
var Simple_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(Simple_setData(), 0.5);
visualization = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('report_Simple'));
visualization.draw(Simple_data, Simple_options);

var Simple_options = { "title": "Test" };
function Simple_setData() {
    var Simple_JsonTable = { cols: [{id: 'ga:date', label: 'date', type: 'string'}, {id: 'ga:visits', label: 'visits', type: 'number'}, {id: 'ga:newVisits', label: 'new visits', type: 'number'}], rows: [{c:[{v: '10/14/2013'}, {v: 333}, {v: 266}]}, {c:[{v: '10/18/2013'}, {v: 161}, {v: 109}]}, {c:[{v: '10/24/2013'}, {v: 224}, {v: 163}]}]};
    return Simple_JsonTable;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that your `Simple_setData` function is a stand-in for the code that grabs data from Google Analytics, and that your data fetching function returns data in the exact same format.  If you don't want to modify the source, you can use a DataView to convert the date strings to Date objects like this:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(Simple_data);
view.setColumns([{
    type: 'date',
    label: Simple_data.getColumnLabel(0),
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        var dateArray = dt.getValue(row, 0).split('/');
        var year = parseInt(dateArray[2]);
        var month = parseInt(dateArray[0]) - 1; // subtract 1 to convert to javascript's 0-indexed months
        var day = parseInt(dateArray[1]);
        return new Date(year, month, day);
    }
}, 1, 2]);
```

Use the DataView when drawing the chart instead of the DataTable:

```
visualization.draw(view, Simple_options);
```

Comment: I am getting a data is not defined error from this line - label: data.getColumnLabel(0) - Thanks for your help

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that - I had copied it from another chunk of code and forgot to change that line.  Fixed now.